# Linux/Ubuntu - Speech Synthesis from Java without using FreeTTS

Tags: java, linux, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I've spent a pair of days trying to make it work: Speech synthesis from Java with FreeTTS on a Ubuntu system and it seems to be far more complicated than what i expected, if possible. There are some problems with this configuration i just can't solve.

So, i've changed my mind and have decided to make it in some other way. I just need to synthesize some texts during the execution of the app, so my question is: Someone knows any other way of making it possible and still be platform-independent (assuming i'll have to install some kind of extra-software in the machine(s) i'll need to run it)?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember there are a plenty of implementations from [F.A.Q. for Java Speech API](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/speech/forDevelopers/jsapifaq.html#implementation), but non of them is OS independent.

Another way is to find (using Google) some new cloud services ([for example](http://www.acapela-group.com/develop-with-text-to-speech.html)) which provides API for voice synthesis.

Comment: Actually that's not a solution for my personal problem, but that's a point i didn't think and could really be a good solution in similar situations. Thanks ;)

Comment: Second statement is good idea to solve your problem. You'll able to create similar solution by yourself. Just create server with FreeTTS on it, which should get text and return media file/stream to your application.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 8.10 has a bug in it's FTTs version; try another software of speech synthesis...